# How do I write a make_vector similar to std::make_tuple?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

Instead of creating vectors like this:

```
  std::vector<int>     v1{1,2,3};
  std::vector<double>  v2{1.1,2.2,3.3};
  std::vector<Object>  v3{Object{},Object{},Object{}};
```

I'd like to create them with a generic function:

```
  auto v1 = make_vector(1,2,3);
  auto v2 = make_vector(1.1,2.2,3.3);
  auto v3 = make_vector(Object{},Object{},Object{});
```

Similar to [std::make_pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) and [std::make_tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple), here was my attempt for a vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template <typename... T>
auto make_vector(T&&... args)
{
    using first_type = typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<T...>>::type;
    return std::vector<first_type>{std::forward<T>(args)...};
}
```

It compiles, but when I attempt to use it:

```
auto vec = make_vector(1,2,3);
```

---

```
m.cpp: In instantiation of ‘auto make_vector(T&& ...) [with T = {int, int, int}]’:
m.cpp:16:30:   required from here
m.cpp:8:78: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class std::tuple_element<0ul, std::tuple<int, int, int> >’
     using first_type = typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<T...>>::type;
                                                                              ^
In file included from m.cpp:3:0:
/usr/include/c++/5/utility:85:11: note: declaration of ‘class std::tuple_element<0ul, std::tuple<int, int, int> >’
     class tuple_element;
           ^
m.cpp:9:60: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class std::tuple_element<0ul, std::tuple<int, int, int> >’
     return std::vector<first_type>{std::forward<T>(args)...};
                                                            ^
In file included from m.cpp:3:0:
/usr/include/c++/5/utility:85:11: note: declaration of ‘class std::tuple_element<0ul, std::tuple<int, int, int> >’
     class tuple_element;
           ^
m.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
m.cpp:16:30: error: ‘void v1’ has incomplete type
   auto v1 = make_vector(1,2,3);
```

How can I make a generic routine,
that uses the first type of the first parameter to instantiate the vector?
How can I forward the arguments as initializer values to the vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just the way you did - both gcc and msvc compile your function with a tiny `#include <tuple>`.

Answer (score 9):

Since you can't use this to create an empty vector anyway, we can avoid the `tuple` dependency by just providing an extra template argument:

```
template <class T0, class... Ts>
auto make_vector(T0&& first, Ts&&... args)
{
    using first_type = std::decay_t<T0>;
    return std::vector<first_type>{
        std::forward<T0>(first),
        std::forward<Ts>(args)...
    };
}
```

which has the added benefit of working if `first` got passed in as an lvalue.

Comment: This code does more allocations than answer by @T.C. below, here is example code https://godbolt.org/z/ojqG6eTes borrowed from https://burnicki.pl/en/2022/08/14/initializing-with-std-initializer_list-involves-copying.html - some explanation available there too.

Comment: @AgainPsychoX It does the same number of allocations in vector (1), it's just that it has to copy every element (because `std::initializer_list`) instead of being able to move (as T.C.'s answer does). What you're showing is the allocations that come from the `string` copies. I agree the other answer is better in that sense (and easier to write in a post-C++17 world where you can just use a fold expression instead of the `expander` trick).

Answer (score 7):

Let's follow [`make_array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/make_array)'s lead, and allow users to either explicitly specify a return type, or use a return type determined by `std::common_type`.

```
template<class T> struct identity { using type = T; };
template<class D, class... Ts>
struct ret : identity<D> {};
template<class... Ts>
struct ret<void, Ts...> : std::common_type<Ts...> {};
template<class D, class... Ts>
using ret_t = typename ret<D, Ts...>::type;

template<class D = void, class... Ts>
std::vector<ret_t<D, Ts...>> make_vector(Ts&&... args) {
    std::vector<ret_t<D, Ts...>>  ret;
    ret.reserve(sizeof...(args));
    using expander = int[];
    (void) expander{ ((void)ret.emplace_back(std::forward<Ts>(args)), 0)..., 0 };
    return ret;
}
```

The use of perfect forwarding suggests that you want to eliminate unnecessary copying; that's not consistent with using the `initalizer_list` constructor which requires a copy of every element. So instead the above code `reserve`s the right amount of space and then `emplace_back`s the elements one by one with the usual pack expansion trick.

`push_back` can be used instead if you don't want to enable explicit conversions, at the cost of a potential move on a type mismatch. However, in this case the type is either explicitly specified by the user or deduced via implicit conversions by `common_type`, so `emplace_back` may be just fine.

Comment: This is the better solution as the other `make_vector` implementation because it also supports move-only types. Thank you very much!

Comment: this does not work for self define class like `explicit FieldInfo(const std::string& name, const char id, const int len, const bool is_required)` I call like this `auto temp = make_vector<FieldInfo>(("Serial Num", 'S', 50, true), ("Customer", 'C', 18, true)`